# Prevent Google OAuth 2.0 redirection for Google Drive API Integration

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/). They have quick start example [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php) which is using Google OAuth 2.0. Using for a web application where user will use drive api for creating folder and save files, edit files etc.

Now the problem is OAuth 2.0 is redirecting the page and for `authCode` and then back to `callbackUrl` again ie. the usual way. Is there any way so that I can get the `authCode` without redirecting the url, by using `cURL` or some library that can do that without redirecting.

I'm using `PHP` for this app.

Answer (score 0):

We currently offer an [alternative flow for installed apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) that doesn't redirect back to an app but outputs the exchange code. In order to be sure that user is explicitly giving permissions to your application, we need to intercept the flow for a user action.

If there are no end users involved in your use case, you may like to take a look at the service accounts: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount Service accounts also provide impersonation for Google Apps domains.